# calculate average using onchange event handler

Tags: javascript

I need to calculate the average of 5 numbers using onchange event handler. I'm new to coding and don't fully understand how onchange works. I also am confused on how to have the return # for my calcAvg function displayin my in 'result' box

```
<! doctype html >

<html lang = "en">
<head>
<title> Calculate Average </title>
</head>

<body>
    Number 1:<input type="number" id="number 1" Value="0" 
onchange="calcAvg()"> </br> //do I put anything in between the ()of 
onchange?
    Number 2:<input type="number" id="number 2" Value="0" 
onchange="calcAvg()"> </br>
    Number 3:<input type="number" id="number 3" Value="0" 
onchange="calcAvg()"> </br>
    Number 4:<input type="number" id="number 4" Value="0" 
onchange="calcAvg()"> </br>
    Number 5:<input type="number" id="number 5" Value="0" 
onchange="calcAvg()"> </br>
    Result :<input type=" number" id="result"> </br>
    <input type= 'button' value='calculate' id= 'calculate'>
    <div id= "result"> </div>// 

    <script>
        function calcAvg ( number 1, number 2 ,number 3, number 4, number 5)
{ 
        return ((number 1 + number 2 +number 3+ number 4+ number 5)/5)
        }
    </script>




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your parameter names are illegal and you should only have one id per element, for starters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed your code a little bit and added classes to the input flieds, instead of ids.

first you should call the onchange event directly in javascript, that way you have to write less code.

html:

```
<input class="number" />
```

js:

```
var numInput = $('.number');

function calcAvg() {
var sum = 0;
// add the current val of each input field to the sum variable
numInput.each(function() {
  sum += Number($(this).val());
  });
  // set the avg to the #result input field
  $('#result').val(sum / numInput.length);
};

// run the calcAvg function everytime the input changes
numInput.change(calcAvg);
```

Here is a working fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/18748/

Answer (score 1):

```
<html lang = "en">
<head>
<title> Calculate Average </title>
</head>

<body>
   Number 1:<input type="number" id="number1" Value="0" 
   onchange="calcAvg()"> </br> 
   Number 2:<input type="number" id="number2" Value="0" 
   onchange="calcAvg()"> </br>
   Number 3:<input type="number" id="number3" Value="0" 
   onchange="calcAvg()"> </br>
   Number 4:<input type="number" id="number4" Value="0" 
   onchange="calcAvg()"> </br>
   Number 5:<input type="number" id="number5" Value="0" 
   onchange="calcAvg()"> </br>
   Result :<input type=" number" id="result"> </br>
<input type= 'button' onClick="calcAvg()" id= 'calculate'>
<div id="result"> </div>// 


 <script>
    function calcAvg () { 
     var num1 = document.getElementById("number1").val() || 0;
     var num2 = document.getElementById("number2").val() || 0;
     var num3 = document.getElementById("number3").val() || 0;
     var num4 = document.getElementById("number4").val() || 0;
     var num5 = document.getElementById("number5").val() || 0;

     document.getElementById("result").value=((num1 + num2 +num3+ num4+ 
     num5)/5);
    }
</script>
```

grab the values from the inputs by their id's and average those values. call the function from the on change attribute. you can call the same function from onclick for the button. set the value by grabbing results ID and adding value to it.

Answer (score 0):

This below code will give your expected output.

```js
$(function(){
 var sum = 0;
 $('input[type=number]').on("change keyup mouseup", function(){
  $("#result").val(calcAvg());
 });
 $('#calculate').on("click", function(){
  $("#result").val(calcAvg());
 });

});
function calcAvg(){
 var s = $("input[type=number]");
 var sum = 0;
 for(var i=0;i<s.length;i++){
  sum += parseInt($(s[i]).val());
 }
 return sum/s.length;
}
```

```css
input{
 display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Number 1:<input type="number" id="number1" Value="0">
    Number 2:<input type="number" id="number2" Value="0"> 
    Number 3:<input type="number" id="number3" Value="0"> 
    Number 4:<input type="number" id="number4" Value="0"> 
    Number 5:<input type="number" id="number5" Value="0"> 
    Result :<input type=" number" id="result"> 
    <input type= 'button' value='calculate' id='calculate'>
```